# obtain multi-dimensional list manipulating the original list in python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to group the list of files based on tiles.

```
files = ['tile1_band1','tile1_band2','tile2_band1','tile2_band2']
tiles = [file[0:5] for file in files]
for tile in tiles:
    new_files = [file for file in files if tile in file]
    print (new_files)
```

The result should be exactly as follows (two dimensional list):

```
[['tile1_band1', 'tile1_band2'], ['tile2_band1', 'tile2_band2']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [zip builtin](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and put a step in your slice:

```
In [26]: a = range(10)

In [27]: zip(a[::2], a[1::2])
Out[27]: [(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> files = ['tile1_band1','tile1_band2','tile2_band1','tile2_band2']
>>> [list(grp) for key, grp in itertools.groupby(files, key=lambda f: f[:5])]
[['tile1_band1', 'tile1_band2'], ['tile2_band1', 'tile2_band2']]
```

If the length of `tile1` part is variable, use `str.split('_', 1)[0]` for key.

```
>>> [list(grp) for key, grp in itertools.groupby(files, key=lambda f: f.split('_', 1)[0])]
[['tile1_band1', 'tile1_band2'], ['tile2_band1', 'tile2_band2']]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> files = ['tile1_band1','tile1_band2','tile2_band1','tile2_band2']
>>> [list(grp) for key, grp in itertools.groupby(files, key=lambda f: f.split('_')[0])]
[['tile1_band1', 'tile1_band2'], ['tile2_band1', 'tile2_band2']]
```

The above code would be more flexible than falsetru's, but it is an improvement upon his original answer.

Comment: falsetru is a genius, but what makes you think he is male ;-)

Comment: @1_CR I know him personally :P

Comment: @falsetru Hey buddy! I think your avatar is misleading XD

Comment: sonofagun @falsetru and gamesbraniac, looking at your avatars anyone would think you were the most attractive gals on SO ;;-)

Comment: @1_CR ahaha. I'm a mega-octocat, I'll blast you with my mega-gun, manly enough for you?